# How to validate Web element if xpath locator is dynamic in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

ID and Xpath is changing for "OK" button every time while saving(Account).

HTML Code:

```
<div class="modal-footer" style="display: block;">
<div class="bootstrap-dialog-footer">
<div class="bootstrap-dialog-footer-buttons">
<button id="fe02d6bd-6058-4871-b0e1-c1e914f64a6a" class="btn btn-     default">Ok</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Xpath:.//*[@id='fe02d6bd-6058-4871-b0e1-c1e914f64a6a']

"ID"/XPath is not constant and it is varying while saving.

Answer (score 0):

use the below code:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.bootstrap-dialog-footer-buttons>button.btn.btn-default"));
```

Comment: is there any frame there? and what exception it is showing?

Comment: No, Actually when i create an account it gets saved and it will pop up a window saying Account created with certain details and on clicking "OK" in that window it will pop up other window saying "Email has been sent to Account Email" , I need to click on "OK" in this particular window which i'm not able to do(as Xpath/ID is dynamic)

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div.bootstrap-dialog-footer-buttons>button.btn.btn-default"}
Command duration or timeout: 270 milliseconds

Comment: it will be better if u give the full html.... theres something more than your provided html...

Answer (score 0):

You can devise your own XPath locator to find the OK button by it's text content like so:

`//button[.='Ok']`

The first part of the XPath expression - `//button` - will select all `<button>` WebElements within the currently focused content.

The second part - `[.='Ok']` - is a predicate that will filter out any WebElements whose exact text content is *not* equal to 'Ok'.

Answer (score 0):

If it is the only OK button available on the page then you can probably use below code.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Ok')]"));
```

Else you can take a reference of parent window and locate a button on it as below

```
WebElement modalWin = driver.findElement(By.id("modal-window-id"));
modalWin.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Ok')]"));
```

Comment: there are two "OK" buttons in the page.Actually when i create an account it gets saved and it will pop up a window saying Account created with certain details and on clicking "OK" in that window it will pop up other window saying "Email has been sent to Account Email" , I need to click on "OK" in this particular window which i'm not able to do(as Xpath/ID is dynamic)

Answer (score 0):

```
    This below code helps to click OK button in any page.
    just call this method with parameter saying OK 

    public void buttonClick(String buttonname){
    WebElemennt button = driver.findelement(by.xpath("//button[text(),'Ok']"))
 or 
 WebElemennt button = driver.findelement(by.cssselector(".btn btn-     default"))

    for(int i=0; i<button.size;i++)
    {
    if(button.get(i).gettext().equalIgnorecase(buttonname))
    {
        button.get(i).click
    }   
    }
    }
Let me know result..
```

Comment: Hi Sneha, can you please try the below code. If it will work please let me know: 
                `//div[@class = 'modal-footer']/div[@class = 'bootstrap-dialog-footer']/div[@class = 'bootstrap-dialog-footer-buttons']/button[text() = 'Ok']`

or we can use the descendant function and code is:  `//div[@class = 'modal-footer']/descendant::button[text() = 'Ok']`